# Copying text from one line to another

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk

I have example file:

```
<i>text</i>
verse 19 3 1 text2
verse 19 3 2 text3
<i>text4</i>
verse 19 4 1 text5
verse 19 4 1 text6
verse 19 4 1 text7
```

And I need to convert it to:

```
pericope 19 3 1 <i>text</i>
verse 19 3 1 text2
verse 19 3 2 text3
pericope 19 4 1 <i>text4</i>
verse 19 4 1 text5
verse 19 4 1 text6
verse 19 4 1 text7
```

How to build regex for this?

Comment: What regex tool are you using for this?

Comment: I can use sed, vim or mcedit. It doesn't matter, as long as it is available on default Linux installation.

Comment: There is no way to use Regex in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/<i>/{p=$0;next} p{s=$0; sub(/ +[^ ]+$/, "", s); print "pericope", s, p; p=""} 1' file
pericope verse 19 3 1 <i>text</i>
verse 19 3 1 text2
verse 19 3 2 text3
pericope verse 19 4 1 <i>text4</i>
verse 19 4 1 text5
verse 19 4 1 text6
verse 19 4 1 text7
```

#### Explanation:

- Save line in variable `p` when you get a line with `<i>`
- From next line strip last field and print `"pericope", s, p`
- Initialize `p` to `""`
- Print next line using default action `1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this in vim and taking the numbers from the first line after the text tag then this regex works:

```
:%s/\(<i>text\d\?<\/i>\n\)\(verse\(\(\s\+\d\+\)\{3}\)\)/periscope\3 \1\2
```